# Cleaner way to restart daemontools services

Tags: linux, centos, daemon, svc, start-stop-daemon

In our product, we had created services using daemontools. One of my service looks like this,

```
/service/test/run
/service/test/log/run (has multilog command to log into ./main dir)
/service/test/log/main/..
```

All the process and its directories are owned by root user. Now there is a security requirement to change like this,

1. Service should run in non-root user.
2. Log main directory should be readable only to user and groups.

For this, I have to change the 'run' file under 'log' directory. Also I need to change the permissions of 'main' directory under it.

Note that all these files under '/service' were owned by test-1.0-0.rpm. When I update my rpm, it overrides the existing run file and got error like this,

```
multilog: fatal: unable to lock directory ./main: access denied
```

I know we shouldn't override the 'run' file at run time. I have planned to follow these steps in my rpm script %post section,

```
//Stop service
svc -d /service/test/log

//Moving the main directory
mv /service/test/log/main /service/test/log/main_old

//Updated run file has code to create main with limited permissions.

//Start service
svc -u /service/test/log
```

In some articles, they suggested to recreate the 'lock' file under 'log/main'. Is there any other cleaner way of doing this without moving 'main' directory ? If not, is it safe to go with the above steps ?

Comment: I think you should post this on http://serverfault.com, it doesn't necessarily belong here.

Comment: @martin, Thanks I have posted this on serverfault.com.